# twilio Error: Fetch resource from "Client/v1/Configuration" failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

i'm using react twilio-chat package for twlio conversation (chat).
when I try to create client it throws this error
Error: Fetch resource from "Client/v1/Configuration" failed.

this is the decoded token I am passing in it

```
  "jti": "SK0cXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "grants": {
    "identity": "agent@gmail.com",
    "chat": {
      "service_sid": "ISaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "data_sync": {
      "service_sid": "default"
    }
  },
  "iat": 1638XXXX,
  "exp": 1638XXXX,
  "iss": "SK0c3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "sub": "AC769XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

here is the code 

import { Client } from "twilio-chat";
import React, { Component } from "react";

var chatClient = {};
    try {
      chatClient = await Client.create(clientToken?.value?.data?.token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Chat Client Error ", error);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe the `@` symbol is a reserved character and should not be used for identities within Twilio Chat. Try an identity that doesn't use the `@` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in token side.
therefore the token did not contain the proper configuration.
thanks for the help.